# Does Javascript Have Open and Close Tags Equivalent to PHP?

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I came across this sort of code on a WordPress admin page:

```
<script type="text/html" id="tmpl-uploader-inline">
    <# if ( data.message ) { #>
        <h3 class="upload-message">{{ data.message }}</h3>
    <# } #>
</script>
```

Are the tags **<#** and **#>** part of javascipt/html syntax or is something else going on here? I tried googling, but google seems to have issues when searching for certain types of symbols. They never make it to the search results.

**UPDATE:**
Based on the answers so far, if the code in the tags is processed by a template engine on the server side, then why is the exact code showing up as page source in the browser? Shouldn't it show just the results of template processing?

Comment: No it is a template language

Comment: What you posted is not JavaScript `type="text/html"` is not `type="text/javascript"`

Comment: @mplungjan I see that now. I just assumed that the presence of "<script></script>" automatically makes it javascript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## General technology

This is a **Javascript template**. Wordpress uses [Backbone.js](http://backbonejs.org/) since [version 3.4.1](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/21664). You can model a View in Backbone.js, which is automatically updated, when the underlying Javascript object changes, [see the corresponding Backbone.js documentation](http://backbonejs.org/#View).

Backbone.js again is based on [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/), which is basically a collection of Javascript utility functions. One of the functions is [`_.template`](http://underscorejs.org/#template), which takes a template string (for example the content of the HTML tag you posted) and a Javascript data object, and replaces variables with values from the data object and evaluates simple expressions.

Example from the underscore.js manual:

```
var compiled = _.template("hello: <%= name %>");
compiled({name: 'moe'});
=> "hello: moe"
```

## Wordpress adaptions

The normal `_.template` syntax would be `<%= name %>`, but for whatever reason the Wordpress developers decided that the so called ERB-style is not appropriate and changed it. You can see that in [`wp-includes/js/wp-util.js`](http://core.svn.wordpress.org/branches/3.9/wp-includes/js/wp-util.js), in version 3.9. around line 20, where the `options` hash is overriden with some regular expressions. Basically the syntax is changed to use `{{ name }}` to output the value of a variable and `<# if ... #>` is being evaluated. (The first one looks a bit like the syntax [mustache.js](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js) uses.)

## Further reading

Here is a tutorial ([part 1](http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/using-backbone-within-the-wordpress-admin-the-back-end--wp-30056), [part 2](http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/using-backbone-within-the-wordpress-admin-the-front-end--wp-30121)) which covers the usage of Backbone.js in Wordpress backends.

And [here](http://www.peterrknight.com/backbone-and-wordpress-resources/) someone gathered a lot of resources around that topic in Wordpress (and in general).

Comment: Thanks very much for the comprehensive answer. It makes much more sense now.

Answer (score 0):

Those tags are not part of JavaScript or HTML, instead they are tags used by a templating engine.

Answer (score 0):

It does have Open and Close tags. Those are

```
<script></script>
```

The other tags

```
<# #>
```

are template tags. The difference between them is that the `<script>` tags will run on the client's browser, and the other ones (`<#`) are run on the server before sending the page to the browser.

Comment: So just to be clear. Any Javascript specified inside <# #> runs on the SERVER? Therefore in order to debug it I need server-side debug, correct?

Comment: What you posted is not JavaScript `type="text/html"` is not `type="text/javascript"`

Comment: You can, but I believe that it would be easier to use the browser. In your case, just add {{data}} before  "<# if", and you have a debugger.

Comment: The `<#` tags are also executed by the browser.

Comment: No, they are processed by the WP engine that is ajaxing them in